# Update Database from Vaadin Table

Tags: java, sql, database, vaadin

I have a database table in which there are already stored some data.

Now I want to have a Vaadin *editable* Table in my page with the data taken from database and when this Vaadin Table is updated (either add a row or edit the existing ones), the database should be updated aswell.

I was so close to that, but I realized I can't use just an INSERT query because  the unique ID constraint is violated.

What can I do in order to achieve that? I really need your help!

**The BeanItemContainer**:

```
public BeanItemContainer createContainer() {                
           BeanItemContainer<Sct> beans = new BeanItemContainer<Sct>(Sct.class);

           beans.addNestedContainerProperty("secti.sid");
           beans.addNestedContainerProperty("secti.isa");
           beans.addNestedContainerProperty("secti.order");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            PS_SECTION section = list.get(i);

                Long ps =  section.getPS_SECTION();
                String na = section.getNAME();
                Long is = section.getISACTIVE();
                Long or = section.getVORDER();

             Object itemId = beans.addBean(new Sct(na, new BeanSect(ps, is, or)));
        }

        return beans;
    }
```

**Here is the save (update) button when clicked:**

```
        ClickListener saveListener = new ClickListener() {          
            private Long s4 = 0L;

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {     

                    Collection<?> itemIds =  table.getItemIds();
                     Item item = null;
                     boolean isSaved = false;
                     PS_SECTION ps = null;
                     List<PS_SECTION> newlist = new ArrayList<PS_SECTION>();
                     int i = 0;

                     for(Object itemId : itemIds){   
                            ps = new PS_SECTION();
                            item = table.getItem(itemId);  

                            Long s1 = (Long) item.getItemProperty("ID").getValue();
                            String s2 = item.getItemProperty("SECTION").getValue().toString();
                            Long s3 = (Long) item.getItemProperty("ORDER").getValue();
                            Long s5 = 0L;

                            ps.setPS_SECTION(s1);
                            ps.setNAME(s2);
                            ps.setVORDER(s3);
                            ps.setISACTIVE(s4);
                            ps.setISGLOBAL(s5);                     
                            newlist.add(ps);
                         }

                            try {
// Here I call the query.                                                       
                              isSaved = dao.insertPsSections(newlist); 

                                if (isSaved){                       
                                    Notification.show("Success ");
                                    unsavedChanges = false;
                                }
                                else if (!isSaved){
                                    Notification.show("Problem");
                                }                        
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                           

            }
        };
```

**Finally, the query:**

```
public boolean insertPsSections(List<PS_SECTION> pssec)  throws SQLException {  
        Boolean sv = false;     
        try {                           
            this.setKeepConnOpen(true);             
            String insertsections = "INSERT INTO PS_SECTION"
                    + "(PS_SECTION,NAME,ISACTIVE,ISGLOBAL,VORDER)"
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

            for (PS_SECTION j : pssec){                                         
                Long section = j.getPS_SECTION();
                String name = j.getNAME();
                Long isa = j.getISACTIVE();
                Long isg = j.getISGLOBAL();
                Long order = j.getVORDER();

                this.simpleUpdate(insertsections, false, section, name, isa, isg, order);
            }

        } finally {
            this.doCommit();
            this.closeConn(true);
            sv=true;
        }
        return sv;
    }
```